# Eigenvalues of product of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, eigenvalues

Let $A,B$ be two Trace class operators with spectral decomposition $\sum_{j\geq 1} \lambda_j \phi_j(\cdot)\otimes \phi_j(\cdot)$ and $\sum_{j\geq 1} \gamma_j \psi_j(\cdot)\otimes \psi_j(\cdot)$ respectively. Can one say anything about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ maybe under further assumptions ? In particular I am curious if clean relationships exist between the eigenvalues of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ and $\lambda_j$, $\gamma_j$, for $j\geq 1$ in some special cases ?

Comment: the eigenvalues of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ are the same those of $AB$.

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ is a positive trace class operator? Otherwise $A^{1/2}$ doesn't make sense to me..

Comment: @Darth Vader Yes indeed